# SharePoint Online - Mobile browser displays tiles rather than standard list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, view, tiles, mobile-view

I have a fairly basic list on SharePoint Online with a few views (same columns, different filters). When viewing any of these on a desktop browser (IE/Edge/Chrome) the items are listed in the standard tabular view.

When viewing any of these on a mobile device (Android and Windows Mobile) tiles are displayed. Even when requesting the Desktop site on the mobile device it insists on displaying tiles.

This makes it quite difficult to navigate through the items when there is 20+ to show.

Is there any way of forcing it to always show standard list view regardless of device?

Also, deactivating mobile view for the whole site doesn't have any impact.

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution !